# There's a way to create live template which run another or multiples live templates?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, live-templates

I want to create a live template for running mixins using sass which includes multiple live templates like flex mixins, canvas mixins, parallax mixins and so on.

May be someone know how to do it without copy paste from other templates

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking whether you can use other live templates in your live templates, then this is not yet supported by IntelliJ IDEs and you can follow that ticket for updates: [IDEABKL-6832](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6832)